# Align itextsharp table

Tags: itext

Does anyone know how to left align a iTextSharp table?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `PdfPTable`'s `HorizontalAlignment` property.

Here's a C# test method you can use to experiment:

```
    private void TestTableCreation() {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("TableTest.pdf", FileMode.Create)) {
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
            doc.Open();

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
            table.WidthPercentage = 50.0f;
            // Options: Element.ALIGN_LEFT (or 0), Element.ALIGN_CENTER (1), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT (2).
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.Format("Cell # {0}", i)));
                cell.FixedHeight = 30.0f;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

                table.AddCell(cell);
            }

            doc.Add(table);
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**table.HorizontalAlignment = 1;**

1:center

0:left

2:right

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it:

1. `cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;`
2. `cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;`