# how to format paragraph string to show content left, Right or middle of pdf document using iTextsharp ' vb

Tags: vb.net, itext

how to format paragraph string to show content left, Right or middle of pdf document using iTextsharp in visual basic and absolute position on the document.

Thanks

as per suggestion by Bruno Lowagie I am using

```
Dim table As New PdfPTable(3)
table.setWidthPercentage(100)
table.addCell(getCell("Text to the left", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT))
table.addCell(getCell("Text in the middle", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER))
table.addCell(getCell("Text to the right", PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT))
document.add(table)

Public Function getCell(ByVal text As String, ByVal alignment As Integer) As PdfPCell
Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(text))
cell.setPadding(0)
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment)
cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER)
Return cell
End Function
```

I am getting error 
cell.setPadding, cell.setHorizontalAlignment,cell.setBorder all are notmember of iTextsharp.Text.pdf.PdfPCell also table.setWidthPercentage(100) shows error argument not specified parameter 'page size'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please browse around and you'll discover that questions similar to yours usually get the comment *What have you tried?* I am the original developer of iText, so please believe me when I say that there are many different ways to achieve this: using `PdfPTable`, using `ColumnText`, using the low-level API,... However, you shouldn't expect that I write a whole chapter explaining the pros and cons of the different approaches. Instead you should narrow down your question so that a single answer suffices.

Comment: Incidentally, I see that almost the exact same question was asked 2 hours before you posted your question. I have answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575142/how-to-align-two-paragraphs-or-text-in-left-and-right-in-a-same-line-in-pdf

Comment: how to use solution 2 in visual basic

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem doing that yourself. If you do have a problem, show us what you've tried. If you don't want to show what you've tried, then what are you doing on StackOverflow???

Comment: Dim table As New PdfPTable(3)
table.setWidthPercentage(100)
table.addCell(getCell("Text to the left", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT))
table.addCell(getCell("Text in the middle", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER))
table.addCell(getCell("Text to the right", PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT))
document.add(table)

Comment: (1) Do not post source code in a comment field (2) Do not copy my code literally. E.g. is there really a ssetWidthPercentage method in iTextSharp??? I think it's table.WidthPercentage you need. Also: there are no method that start with lower case in iTextSharp!!! (3.) Why do you omit the getCell method???

Comment: yes if not what to do

Comment: Update your question. If that's impossible, delete this question and post a new one. In its current form, your question is not suited for StackOverflow. It's not because you're a newbie that you should act as one ;-)

Comment: I have corrected my question

Comment: Yes, but you haven't read any of the documentation! **You are copying the JAVA methods!** Why don't you convert them to the corresponding .NET parameters?

Comment: pl give me documentation about itext to read

Comment: The best free book to start with is probably [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). It contains hundreds of code snippets in Java, C#, etc... Once you've read that book, take a look at our [learn](http://itextpdf.com/learn) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a visual basic programmer (the last time I used visual basic was in 1996 and I said: *never again!*), but just by using Google, I adapted your example like this:

```
Dim table As New PdfPTable(3)
table.WidthPercentage = 100
table.AddCell(GetCell("Text to the left", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT))
table.AddCell(GetCell("Text in the middle", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER))
table.AddCell(GetCell("Text to the right", PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT))
document.Add(table)

Public Function GetCell(ByVal text As String, ByVal alignment As Integer) As PdfPCell
    Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(text))
    cell.Padding = 0
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = alignment
    cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER
    Return cell
End Function
```

This is commonly known:

- Methods in Java start with lower case; methods in .NET start with upper case, so when people ask you to use Java code as pseudo code and to convert Java to .NET, you need to change methods such as `add()` and `addCell()` into `Add()` and `AddCell()`.
- Member-variables in Java are changed and consulted using getters and setters; variables in .NET are changed and consulted using methods that look like properties. This means the you need to change lines such as `cell.setBorder(border);` and `border = cell.getBorder();` into `cell.Border = border` and `border = cell.Border`.

iText and iTextSharp are kept in sync, which means that, using the two rules explained above, a developer won't have any problem to convert iText code into iTextSharp code.

When in doubt about a method, one can always do as I did, Google for these methods and properties! You'll find examples such as:

- [Align itextsharp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145808/align-itextsharp-table)
- [iTextSharp Table Cell Spacing Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231770/itextsharp-table-cell-spacing-possible)
- ...

If you want a whole bunch of examples in one place, download [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html)